# Description of a Tab

Tags: navigation, tab

Designing an enterprise application with 2 tab options that will render separate tables. I want to add a description to the tab to make it clearer to the users, and provide more context. Here are 3 options I am considering with their pros and cons. Would love community inputs :)

**Option 1:** onHover interaction, very lightweight and non disruptive. However the description has to be very small for it to work.

**Option 2:** Information icon, user has to hover/ click on the information icon to see the description. It calls some attention, however I am unsure if tabs have information icon?

**Option 3:** Persistent information, which user will learn about if they use the platform 3-4 times. Could be redundant, and since there is a table rendered under this tab, it will add extra space up top with not so important information.

[image: Option 1 to 3 for rendering tab descriptions]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a combination of #1 and #3...

Provide a mouseover popup with a *brief* description. A "More..." link can be provided to provide additional information (...*more* on that later.):

[image: tab flyover]

Once the tab is selected provide an expandable/collapsible information link with a full description:

[image: tab open]

"i" clicked:

[image: tab info]

Clicking the "More..." link, presented in the flyover, automatically opens the tab and the additional information.

Instead of using the information icon on the Tab page, a simple "About this page +/-" activator link can be used to expand and collapse the long page description.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what many applications do, a show/hide tooltips button, so the user can choose when to see or not the tooltips or decide to stop seeing them once seen for the first time.

[image: show]

[image: hide]

Comment: oh wow! I didn't know this feature exists in some applications. Could you share those examples/ names so that I may look them up?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/forms/show-or-hide-tooltips

Answer (score 0):

- **Option 1**
  I think this option is not ideal because user doesn't have enough
  information to see the tooltip.
- **Option 2 & option 3**
  In my opinion, to figure out what's best for this project, it's best to have data from conducting user research. If >60% of users understand the content without context, then it will be okay to use option 02 whereas if

> 60% of users fail to understand the content without context, then option 03 would be the best to go ahead with.

Answer (score 0):

you can always have a dismissible information message-bubble within each tab, users who have read that can dismiss it and not see them again (provided you have a centralised FAQ/knowledge-base around)

---

however, I think the tab should be somewhat self-explanatory on what data it contains.